# Why my hardwood floor is buckling

Tags: wood, flooring, hardwood-floor, subfloor, carpentry

I’ve replaced the carpet in one of our room with hardwood, about a year ago, which buckled up by the end of the summer this year. 
There is a crowlspace under the house, where I found no leaks, but mold.
I’ve put felt paper under and nailed the boards down.
I didn’t replace the particle board with plywood. Could that be the cause of the moisture and bucking?
The particle board under the moisture barrier is molded bad.

What I should’ve bean doing otherwise, or the problem is not due to installation?

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: The particleboard was moldy when you installed the hardwood flooring over it?

Comment: No. The particleboard wasnt moldy before installation. Someone told me, Its happened because I put the hardwood on particleboard. I don’t know why plywood would make a difference.? The particleboard is black moldy under the  vapor barrier .

Comment: The mold underneath the vapor barrier may be a problem too, but it's not the cause of your floorboard buckling. That's almost certainly from seasonal changes in the width of the floorboards.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of buckling in hardwood floors is **nearly always** from failure to leave adequate space (generally concealed under trim) at the sides of the room.

Wood shrinks and swells as the humidity changes with the seasons, and mostly across the width of the boards (very little end to end.) If installed without adequate space to allow for this to occur the floor will buckle when it's reached the walls and swells/expands more.

If in addition to normal seasonal changes you have excessive moisture, the "normal" expansion space may prove inadequate.

Comment: Is this true for nail-down hardwood or is this just about a floating laminate floor?

Comment: It is absolutely true for nail-down hardwood. If anything, laminate moves somewhat less.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, sounds like there may not be enough space between the edges of your floor, and the bottom plate of your walls. Wood will expand, and when it doesn't have anywhere to go, your boards will push against each other and raise up, kind of like a mountain.